# Using Test::Unit::Data

Tags: ruby, testunit, data-driven-tests

I am trying to create some data driven API tests using Test::Unit for ruby.  The eventual intention is to read a series of test cases in from a .csv file.  In looking for something that would be the equivalent of @dataprovider for testng, I found a class called Data which looks like exactly what I need.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/test-unit/test-unit/Test/Unit/Data/ClassMethods

However, when I tried to create a test case to try to get it working, I get an error saying

"initial_test.rb:4:in `<class:InitialTest>': undefined method`data' for InitialTest:Class (NoMethodError)
"

code I was running:

```
    require "test/unit"
class InitialTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    data("true" => [true],
         "false" => [false])
    def test_true_is_true(data)
        value = data
        assert(false, "FAIL!")
    end
end
```

I can't seem to find any mention of the Data class outside of the documentation.  Has anyone used this class?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this module in particular, but since `data` is defined as an instance method on `Test::Unit::Data` and `Test::Unit::Data` is a Module, this works:

```
class YourTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Test::Unit::Data

  data(…)
end
```

This said, you're going to want to take a closer look at the docs you linked since your example usage is looking like copy-pasta.

Comment: Thanks.  I mostly just wanted to get a bare basics test working so I could make sure I had the syntax right before trying to do anything more complicated.  This is my first attempt at using Test::Unit.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was that I was using an older version of Ruby that did not include the class I was trying to use.  Updating to a newer version solved the problem.